# Is it possible to load ads delayed (on-demand) with Google AdManager?

Tags: web-applications, google-ad-manager

When I'm loading the ads instantly (first calling `googletag.defineSlot(...)`, and then loading the ad with `googletag.display(...)`), everything works as expected.

Now, since this is a web app, I need to load the ads on-demand. So, when I load the ad delayed (the ad code is first in a `<template>` tag and only rendered into the dom when needed), they don't output any errors, but they stay empty. So I'm guessing it is not meant to be used like that.

Is there an official way to load ads delayed? Because I have 3 different ad units from which I only need to display one in regards of the current available space (device orientation, column layout).

Comment: As a workaround, I now load each ad unit separately in a dedicated html page which I then load into the site via iframe. The downside is, however, that it takes some time to load...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to control ads loading you can use [disableInitialLoad()](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/reference#googletag.PubAdsService_disableInitialLoad) :

> Disables requests for ads on page load, but allows ads to be requested with a PubAdsService.refresh call. This should be set prior to enabling the service. Async mode must be used; otherwise it will be impossible to request ads using refresh.

With this method, you can call a specific ad slot when you want, by using the [refresh()](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/reference#googletag.PubAdsService_refresh) fonction.

There is a dedicated guide on the official documentation about its use : [see here](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/guides/control-ad-loading) for full working demo.

Last but not least : keep in mind that as soon as you define a tag, you can not anymore move the attached DOM node within the DOM : it will render empty ad slots. Details [here](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/common_implementation_mistakes#scenario-8:-moving-slot-containers-within-the-dom-after-calling-display).

Comment: Awesome, thank you! But the ad tag can be rendered delayed and multiple times (deleting the dom element and creating it again)?

Comment: if you refresh() the adslot, then the generated iframe will be replaced by the new one (ad call response) > no need to erase the dom node

Comment: Yes, OK, I appreciate that. But, the (responsive) design loads different ad units depending on the available screen size dynamically (rendered via `<template>` tag such that the ad unit only gets rendered when needed. So in case someone turns the device for example (landscape > portrait) or changes the site layout (2 columns > 1 column), different ad units get automatically rendered...

Comment: you might be interested in the sizemapping builder to define eligible ad sizes to each screen size : https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/reference#googletag.sizemappingbuilder
Then if the user rotate the device, you can "update" (refresh) the adcall and get the correct size creative

Comment: I heard of that. However, our agency told me that in our case we can't use sizemapping. Don't know why exactly.

Comment: In my case, I will have multiple ad slots, but I need to only show one of them at a time. Can I call refresh on a single ad slot only?

Comment: Also, since I use the same ad unit in different locations (depending on the user interaction), is it possible to load the same ad unit multiple times?

Comment: Because I couldn't find an answer myself to my two recent questions (above comments) I implemented the ads the classic way, but loaded them via iframe. It works, but when we went live with it, the revenue dropped drastically - so we don't know what to do right now...

Comment: Since we have a web app, the ads appear at different places at different times depending on the user interaction (there is no new page load, sinec it's a single page app)